# Pizza, Threading, Waiting, Notifying. What does it mean?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two methods (in C#):

```
List<Pizza> CookPizza(List<Order>);
List<HappyCustomers> DeliverPizza(List<Pizza>);
```

These operations have no common objects (aside from the pizzas that are passed from one to the other), and are thread-safe.  They each take several seconds to execute and they each use different resources (oven vs car).  As such, I want to run them at the same time.

How do I organize the threading with these constraints:

- I know all of the Orders at the start (say, I have 100,000 of them).  An Order can consist of multiple Pizzas and I don't know how many Pizzas are in any Order until after those Pizzas are cooked. (wierd I know).  Generally an Order has 1 Pizza, but there can be as many as 10.
- The number of active Pizzas should not generally exceed 100.  This includes Pizzas freshly cooked and Pizzas being delivered.  This is a soft limit, so I can exceed it some (for example, when a big Order was cooked).  The hard limit is probably closer to 500.
- Both of the operations are more efficient when they are given a lot of work.  Generally, CookPizza is most efficient when given at least 20 Orders.  Deliver Pizza is most efficient when given at least 50 Pizzas.  That is to say, I will see performance degrade if I give fewer items to those methods than those amounts.  It's fine to use fewer items if that's all that is left.

The main issue I'm stuggling with is how the methods may need to wait on each other.

- DeliverPizza might need to wait around for CookPizza to complete 50.
- CookPizza might need to wait around for DeliverPizza to reduce the number of active Pizzas to 100.

Comment: Do the methods have to have those signatures?

Comment: +1 if you clicked this link because of the word PIZZA

Comment: @jgauffin, no.  What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I 'd approach this problem using an event-based model to begin with.

Let's say we have a `PizzaDispatcher` object which is given the orders. The dispatcher begins calling `CookPizza` with a set number of orders from the initial empty state. When pizzas are cooked the `CookPizza` function notifies the dispatcher that a pizza has been cooked (perhaps by a callback that you provide as a parameter). When a pizza is delivered the `DeliverPizza` function does the same.

The `PizzaDispatcher` would now have enough information to decide when and how many pizzas should be turned in for cooking or for delivery based on the number of cooked pizzas and outstanding deliveries.

This can be refactored to using events instead of callbacks etc, but I 'm posting it for the idea, not the specifics of the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You want a concurrent buffer- probably a concurrent queue, and you may need several. You want a concurrent queue of orders. You call CookOrder with the concurrent queue. When CookOrder returns, you call it again with the new contents of the queue. Here you can only post the first 100 items or something if you want. Here the Orders are effectively batched by the queue and CookOrder is always running. Then you repeat the process again with Pizzas.

Comment: I upvoted this, but... merely having a threadsafe collection doesn't really help with the signalling that I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all you need is a `PizzaManager` that decides what `Pizza` order to cook first, and then passes them along to the `DeliveryBoy` for them to be delivered. Then once the `DeliveryBoy` `DeliversPizza`, then he reports back to the `PizzaManager` to retrieve the next `Pizza` order. The `PizzaManager` takes care of all math related to optimizing the priority of which orders to cook and deliver. The `DeliveryBoy` would probably have the `PizzaManager` as a `delegate`.

Answer (score 0):

one thought

add a member variable to Pizza to track is_cooked.
then during CookPizza, set that member to true when done,
then during DeliverPizza, check that member before proceeding.

Comment: Better I think to track the Pizza state by what queue it is on. When delivered just delete the pizza object or place on a delivered queue.